# Наклон изображения при наведении

Tags: javascript, css

Помогите как можно добиться эффекта как на сайте [fixedgroup.com](http://fixedgroup.com):
При на ведении мышки в изображении идет наклон.

Comment: Свойство [transform](https://webref.ru/css/transform) и функция трансформации matrix3d

Comment: Делать это можно отслеживая положение курсора через `mousemove`, расчёт нового положения и смена через `transform: matrix3d()`.

Answer (score 1):

Весь код, необходимый для этого, есть на сайте [fixedgroup.com](http://fixedgroup.com) - его очень легко посмотреть.
Как заметили выше, используется CSS-эффект `transform: matrix3d()`.

Comment: Это я знаю.Но как это сделать спомощью мышки?.

Comment: @Sauron, просто же - используйте событие `mousemove`, там берите координаты курсора (лучше `clientX/clientY`) и вперёд - модифицировать матрицу.

Comment: Тут не все знают полностью язык jquery и css(matrix3d).Для этого и чтобы помогли люди дали пример пишут вопросы.А не для простых советов.

Comment: @Sauron в вопрос и в разборки по поводу знаний влезать не буду. Отмечу только, что jQuery - это библиотека, а не язык.

Comment: @Sauron, вот прочитайте: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Конкретно, цитирую, "Спрашивайте о реальной проблеме, с которой вы столкнулись. Опишите в деталях, что вы делаете и какой результат пытаетесь получить" - вы же спрашиваете "как сделать как у них". Что вы пытались сделать? Покажите свой код. Какую ошибку выдает? Что не работает? Здесь никто писать за вас код не будет.